# Change elements close "beehive"

Tags: proximity, beehive

I have a question for you that is tormenting me a lot.

Look at the code attached, I wish to MouseHover on one of the circles others change to climb as is now going on with the mouse "box_4A".

As you can see the code is extremely complex and not very intelligent ...
Do you know any shortcut? Or maybe I could say the right way : )

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqOqPY)

```
$('.box_4A').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.circle').stop(true,true).toggleClass('generic_lv0', 500, 'easeInOutQuad');
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.box_3A, .box_4B, .box_5B').find('.circle').stop(true,true).toggleClass('generic_lv1', 500, 'easeInOutQuad'); }, 50);
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.box_2A, .box_3B, .box_4C').find('.circle').stop(true,true).toggleClass('generic_lv2', 500, 'easeInOutQuad'); }, 75);
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.box_1A, .box_2B, .box_2C, .box_3C, .box_4D, .box_5D').find('.circle').stop(true,true).toggleClass('generic_lv3', 500, 'easeInOutQuad'); }, 100);
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.box_1B, .box_1C, .box_1D, .box_2D, .box_3D, .box_1E, .box_2E, .box_3E, .box_4E').find('.circle').stop(true,true).toggleClass('generic_lv4', 500, 'easeInOutQuad'); }, 125);
});
```